# Selenium Grid shutdown command when running as standalone

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Does Selenium Grid (v4) have a shutdown command when running as standalone (without -role option)?

I do not want to use `kill` commands, I know that I can do `lsof -t -i :4444 | xargs kill`, but I would like to avoid that